# sharing savegames between a demo and a full version in Android

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am currently developing an Android Game and my goal is to create a free/*demo* version of the game, so that the users can try it out. But I also want that **the savegames from the demo are automatically imported in the full version**.

The savegames I store in the applications *private storage* and they are basically **JSON** strings mapping several Java Objects. The user can create as many "new games" as he wants and there is an "auto save" and a "manual save" file for each game he started. To keep track of all the files, I have a list containing the filenames and some additional information (like the players name etc).

So basically there are quite a lot of small files handling the savegames. This may not be the most elegant approach, but it works quite well.

**So here is my question:** Lets say the user has started a game in the demo version (so there will be 3 files saved in the private storage of the demo version). *How can I now access these files from within the full version?*

The two versions won't be much different. They are actually the same, despite the limitations of the demo version. But I would be using the same code base.

I know there has been quite some questions about this issue in this forum and elsewhere, but I was not able to find a suitable solution. All I could find involved either:

- storing the files in a **world readable storage** (like the SD-card) or
- using the **SharedPreferences**

But I neither want the user to be able to read the savegames (or even alter it – because this could mess up the game) – so no sd-card, nor can I use the SharedPreferences, because each single savegame has approx. 200 lines of code (many many java objects translated into JSON) and mapping all those values and objects into some kind of key-value structure used for the SharedPreferences seems quite impossible to me.

**Is this all messed up, or does anyone have an idea?**

Thank you for taking the time, looking forward to hear your ideas!

- Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I see just 2 Solutions:

The first is a WorldReadable SharedPreferences. You said, that you store JsonStrings, so there is no need to map them any further down, if you can make Objects out of your json-strings (I like to use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this kind of work), you can simply store these 
Strings inside SharedPreferences.

The second Way is to bother with [ContentProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and implement a ContentResolver interface. This is the safest way I can imagine for your use-case, but you have to implement a lot for it

Comment: Haha, I don't believe it, of course you are right! I can simply save the JSON strings inside the SharedPreferences. And yes, I am using Gson, too – pretty nice library for that. Thank you, I will immediately try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

**What you can't avoid**

There are two things that you can't avoid:

- If the user decides to root the phone, you can't prevent a user from accessing it, doesn't matter what you do to make it harder.
- If you want a second app to access the same data (the saved games) in a non rooted device, there would always be a away for user access it from outside your apps.

**What can you do to make it harder**

- You can encrypt (i.e. using device IMEI) the data before store it in a file or shared preferences (together with a hash to prevent changes)
- You can store the data in a SQLite database (would require more knowledge to change it), and encrypt before store it (even harder).
- You can use [SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/) to store it in a ciphered database (encryption will be transparent).

Regards.

Comment: yes you are right, I may not be able to stop users from reading the saved games unless using more extreme measures. Thanks for pointing out some possibilities (I especially like the encryption), but maybe it is not worth the effort. If a user decides to read or alter the files.. well it's his game :) I just didn't want him to accidentally mess up anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared Content Provider (here the general documentation about ContentProviders http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

you then have to declare it as exportable using the flag:  android:exported="true" in the manifest

example:

```
<provider android:name="[yourpackage_here].SavegameProvider"
 android:authorities="[yourpackage_here].SavegameProvider"
 android:exported="true" />
```

you will be able to open it within your new app.